# Best graph to show different y domains on same canvas

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, visualization

This is more of a design decision for me. I have two different time series sets of data with y-domains say, [0,10000] and [0,10]. The X-axis is a series of time( say last one month). Both the quantities are related to each other and together convey a picture about the system. I initially tried drawing 2 line graphs in the same canvas but the second graph is almost invisible for obvious reasons. Are there any other graphs which depict such data more efficiently?

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped) maybe?

Comment: You can draw them as two unstacked paths (i.e. a trendline) or as pairs of rects (i.e. a grouped bar chart, where each pair of bars is a point in time), but in either case you'd want to use two separate scales. [Here's what the two-scale trendline looks like](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/charts/2_y_axes.php) in the Excel world. To reduce confusion, each axis must be properly labeled (or colored) to help viewers associate the geometry with the appropriate axis.